# Group by several parameters in Groovy SQL-like

Tags: groovy, group-by

I have the following JSON:

```
     [
   {
     "Country": "Norway",
     "Dept": "2",
     "Hours": "08,00"
   },
   {
     "Country": "Norway",
     "Dept": "2",
     "Hours": "08,00"
   },
   {
     "Country": "Sweden",
     "Dept": "1",
     "Hours": "08,00"
   },
   {
     "Country": "Sweden",
     "Dept": "2",
     "Hours": "08,00"
   }
 ]
```

I want to write a `groupBy` country and dept (and if I add more parameters) and get the total number of worked hours in the following way :

```
     [
   {
     "Country": "Norway",
     "Dept": "2",
     "Hours": "16,00"
   },
   {
     "Country": "Sweden",
     "Dept": "1",
     "Hours": "08,00"
   },
   {
     "Country": "Sweden",
     "Dept": "2",
     "Hours": "08,00"
   }
 ]
```

How is it possible to add `GroupBY` multiple times in groovy so that I achieve that? I see that I need to add some `collectEntries` but I am not sure how

Comment: Can you show us your SQL query?

Comment: My only opinion is don't use hours as string for math.

Comment: I agree with you, @fsi about string for math. However, it is a backend system that returns the JSON in that format and we are not supposed to change the format of the properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you looking for, but I didn't like how I did iterate on map and using `<<` to a new list.

Ps; your variable `Hours` is a string, I did mine as numeric.

```
def map = objJson.groupBy({it.Country}, {it.Dept}).collectEntries { k, v ->
    [k, v.collect{ [Hours: it.value.Hours.sum(), Dept: it.value.Dept[0], Country: it.value.Country[0]] }]
}

def list = []
map.each(){ k, v ->
    v.each{
        list << it
    }
}
return new JsonBuilder(list).toPrettyString()
```

Comment: +1 Rest of the script(after the map statement) can be reduced to `println new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(map.collect{ k, v -> v }.flatten()).toPrettyString()`

Comment: Or some more condensed script - http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5157102054014976

Comment: Oh that's nice, I read it on docs, didn't know about this method flatten.

Comment: With my colleagues here we got also this one: `def result = new JsonSlurper().parseText(hours)

def grouped = [:]
result.each {
  def key = "${it.HoursType}_${it.Date}".toString()
  grouped[key] = grouped.get(key, new BigDecimal(0)) + new BigDecimal(it.Hours.toString().replace(",", "."))
}
grouped.each { key, value ->
  println "$key : $value"
}` which is pretty similar to the solution already placed

Comment: Ugh, if you are working only hours, that is ok, but using minutes? thats bad... (if you do: 01,40 + 01,20 would be : 02,60 instead of 03,00 ...) so in safe case, use datetime...

Comment: Or I misconception your string about hour.